# Does Ubuntu Snappy Core work with Raspberry Pi 1?

Tags: raspberrypi, ubuntu-core

Does Ubuntu Snappy Core work with Raspberry Pi 1 (the original model)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Snappy supports ARMv7 and x86-64 platforms**. Recommended development environments include the BeagleBone Black and Odroid-C1 open spec boards. **The Raspberry Pi is disqualified due to its ARM11 processor**, which doesn’t run ARMv7.

Source: http://linuxgizmos.com/lightweight-snappy-ubuntu-core-os-targets-iot/

Answer (score -1):

`Snappy Ubuntu Core` requires `Raspberry Pi 2` according to the official download page of Raspberry .

Check [official download](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) - click on `+ More info` just above the download buttons for `Snappy Ubuntu Core`.